# Copy from 1 table to table 2, no duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Table 1: id, fileref, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, accno, 7, 8, 9, etc, etc...

table 2: id, fileref, accno

can someone please help me create a sql query to copy table 1 id, fileref, accno to table 2 without duplicates, because table 2 already has alot of information like the stripped down version of table 1, but i now imported more information to table 1 and need to move the id, fileref, accno to table 2 without duplication, thanks

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT id, fileref, accno
FROM table1 T
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                 FROM table2 TT
                 WHERE (T.id = TT.id
                       AND
                       T.fileref = TT.fileref
                       AND 
                       T.accno   =  TT.accno)
                 )
```

Comment: this one worked, and according to time was first :P sorry guys thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Let's make test data;

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Table1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Table1
GO
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (id int, fileref varchar(10), accno varchar(10))
INSERT INTO #Table1 (id, fileref, accno)
VALUES
(1,'File1','Acct1')
,(2,'File2','Acct2')
,(3,'File3','Acct3')
,(4,'File4','Acct4')
,(5,'File5','Acct5')

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Table2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Table2
GO
CREATE TABLE #Table2 (id int, fileref varchar(10), accno varchar(10))
INSERT INTO #Table2 (id, fileref, accno)
VALUES
(1,'File1','Acct1')
,(2,'File2','Acct2')
```

This query is going to make sure that there's no matches of all three fields.

```
INSERT INTO #Table2 (id, fileref, accno)
SELECT 
a.id
,a.fileref
,a.accno
FROM #Table1 a
LEFT JOIN #Table2 b
    ON a.id = b.id
    AND a.fileref = b.fileref
    AND a.accno = b.accno
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

The result of this query is that will insert the missing 3 rows into table2 from table1.

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO table2(id, fileref, accno)

SELECT t1.id, t1.fileref, t1.accno

FROM table1 t1 

JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.fileref = t2.fileref AND t1.accno = t2.accno

WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
```

Should do it.

EDIT:

Cut the distinct part, join the tables on the 3 values and check where the ID of table 2 equals NULL;

Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: what about duplicates?

Comment: @RichBenner the DISTINCT in your select will only take 1 of each instance. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: @TanguyB *table 2 already has alot of information like the stripped down version of table 1* so you need to check if there is no exact same rows in table 2

Comment: @TanguyB OP has clearly stated that table2 already has data in it and he doesn't want to insert the same data again.

Comment: @RichBenner my bad over red it. JOIN The table on the 3 values and check where the ID doesn't exist then.

Comment: @TanguyB yes, i know, check my answer. I'd suggest updating your answer to meet the requirements of the OP now that they're clear to you.

Comment: you're also going to have to use your table aliases for this to work, otherwise you'll have ambiguous columns. (Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 12 Ambiguous column name 'id'.) It's always best to make some test data so that you can ensure your code is working correctly.

Comment: @RichBenner indeed, sorry my sql seems to be messy today haha.